# transferspreadsheet using a sql query

Tags: sql, vba

I have an access vba module that is doing transfer spreadsheet.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "MyTable", "\\hello\world.xls", True, "a1:b1000"
```

I'm in the process of converting the access db to `sql` and replacing all the modules with `sql queries.`

what is the sql code for this vba code? `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8, "MyTable", "\\hello\world.xls", True, "a1:b1000"`

Appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to move to SQL server? Or do you want to keep using Access but for some reason do away with the VBA?

Comment: i'm moving everything to SQL server...

Comment: as you commented on the other guy's answer, you could do a `SELECT INTO` with a csv or excel datasource. I replied with more information below

Comment: so i can use a distributed query to import data from a spreadsheet...

SELECT * INTO XLImport5 FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Customers$]')

but when i run the above query, i get an error: The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" has not been registered.

so it tries to use JET for spreadsheets? i would have thought that it was a more native driver...

do you know of a way i can do it without using JET?

Comment: This is the article that I was reading to verify that I was giving correct information. You will probably find your answer there http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Comment: The a1:b1000 is the range of cells to import - cell A1 to B1000

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no directly equivalent feature but there's a couple of approaches you could take:

You can use SQL Server Integration Services to read data from spreadsheets and push it into databases (not just SQL Server).

Or attach a SQL table inside Access and continue to use Access as a data bridge between Excel and SQL Server.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... for importing data from excel, i could use this sql query: SELECT * INTO XLImport3 FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=C:\test\xltest.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')...[Customers$]... but what i would like to know is what the transferspreadsheet is doing with those parameters... "a1:b1000" --  this means select top (1000)? DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 8: what does the number '8' convey here?

Comment: @pradeep the number 8 is the parameter for the type of spreadsheet (the format of the excel document). 8 would indicate excel 97-2000. A list of parameter values can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225982(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly the same you should be able to very easily accomplish the same result by continuing to use the Transfer Spread Sheet into your Access Database... then you want to take it to the next step and transfer that table into your SQL Server Database like so:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTableName, strFileName, True
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=YOUR-SERVER;Database=YOUR-DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes", acTable, strTableName, strTableName
```