# Importing data from Excel into a Linked SQL Server Table in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access

I am attempting to import a large Excel file into Access, into a linked table connected to SQL Server. When I left click on the linked table in Access, and select "import", I'm shown three options. Whatever option I select, it seems to create a new local table with the same name, rather than importing the Excel data into the SQL Server table that is linked. Does anyone know what I can do? Basically I'd like to use Access to access a SQL Server table, and be able to paste or import a large amount of data from Excel to the linked table in Access.

Comment: That's not what a linked table is, nor is that how a link table functions. A link table is more like a view of a remote table. You, however, have two remote tables. 1) a sql server table that is empty and 2) an excel worksheet which is full. Access probably isn't the best tool to get 2 into 1, instead consider using SSMS to import the excel data into your sql server table.

Comment: Simply append into linked table from that new local table of same name: `INSERT INTO myLinkedMSSQLTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...) SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM myExcelLocalTable`

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying import excel into a local table, and then run a query to insert the data into the linked table?

Comment: @Justin ... yes

Answer (score 0):

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml,"dbo.Yourtablename","your file path and name with extension",true (only if the excel file has field names that match your table field names),choose your excel cell range (example: A2:A324)
```

Comment: Downvoted because this will create a new local table named `dbo_Yourtablename`.  It does not push data into SQL Server.  From what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428860/transferspreadsheet-using-a-sql-query) it does not seem to be possible to import directly to SQL Server using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.